# Deleting a record from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, is it `@variable.delete` or `@variable.destroy`

Comment: This isn't really a Ruby question, it's a question for whatever ORM you are using, which, since you're using Rails, is probably ActiveRecord. How about rephrasing your question and title to reflect the ORM instead of Ruby. As is, it's a confusing question.

Comment: yeah, you're right, Ill change that

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`@variable.destroy` will call all callbacks (before_destroy etc.) as well as ensure associations are respected. `@variable.delete` just calls the raw database query to delete the object. You're generally much safer off using `destroy` even if it's more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using ActiveRecord, and that `@variable` is an instance of an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, you call `@variable.destroy`.